# PHP :Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i am trying to  fetch data as per following query

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM residential "; 
            if($type!=""){
             $query.=" AND  type='$type'";
            }
            if($unit_type!=""){
             $query.=" AND  unit_type='$unit_type'";
            }
            if(($min_price!="") && ($max_price!="")){
             $query.=" AND  price BETWEEN '$min_price' AND '$max_price' ";
            }
            if(($min_bedrooms!="") && ($max_bedrooms!="")){
             $query.=" AND bedrooms BETWEEN '$min_bedrooms' AND '$max_bedrooms'";
            }
            if($query==FALSE){
                echo mysqli_error($connect);
                die;
            }
            $result= mysqli_query($connect,$query);
```

this is how i use it

```
<div class="row">
    <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0):?>
    <?php while($row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)):
        print_r($row);
        die;
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row property-listing">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
               <img src="images/1.png" class="img-responsive full-width"> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 property-desc">
                <h3>AED<br/>  <?php echo $row['price'];?></h3>
                <h5>Unit Type: <?php echo $row['unit_type'];?></h5>
                <h5>Available for :<?php echo $row['type'];?></h5>
                <h5>Location :<?php echo $row['area'];?></h5>
                <h5>Bedrooms :<?php echo $row['bedrooms'];?></h5>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php else:
        echo 'We found no record for your search criteria ';
        echo '<a href="index.html">Refine Search</a>'
        ?>

    <?php endif;?>

</div>
```

This is what i get as error

> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be
>   mysqli_result, string given

values being posted and fetched are correct but something is wrong with query , Please help me sort it out

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this code

```php
$query= "SELECT * FROM residential ";
```

Into

```php
$query= "SELECT * FROM residential WHERE 1";
```

And change this code

```php
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0):?>
    <?php while($row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)):
        print_r($row);
        die;
    ?>
```

To

```php
<?php 
$res = mysqli_query($con, $query); //replace $con with your db connection variable
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0):?>
    <?php while($row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)):
        print_r($row);
        die;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$query` is your query string not your result set.So just use `$result`

```
<?php if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0):?>
    <?php while($row=  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding to `mysqli_num_rows()` and `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` the query string when it expects `mysqli_result` - In your case its the variable `$result`.

Answer (score -1):

In your Sql query you do not include a WHERE clause.

If you want to concatenate your query with other argument for the first sql query add a **WHERE** clause to your first sql string like this

`$query= "SELECT * FROM residential WHERE table_id!=0";`
Here **table_id** is the primary key of your **table**.it will be a good practice for concatenating the query.
after that you can add another values to concatenate the query like

```
if($type!=""){
   $query.=" AND  type='$type'";
}
```

so your final query something looks like

```
SELECT * FROM residential WHERE table_id!=0 AND type='$type'
```

Next here you are passing `$query` to **mysqli_num_rows** you should pass the `$result` for this